# Vuex store - pushing item in state to a state array causes the previous item in the array to change to the current state item

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to make a todo list with Vue and Vuex. In my state, I have a todo and the todoList. Updating the todo in the state works fine. And then I try to push the todo to the todoList. That works fine as well. But as soon as I push the second todo, the first one changes to the same as the second todo...

```
<input type='text' :value="title" @input="updateTitle" placeholder="Title" ref="title">
<div class='addIcon' v-html="plusSVG" @click="addTodo"></div>

computed: {
      ...mapState({
        title: state => state.todo.title
      })
},
methods: {
      updateTitle(e) {
      this.$store.commit('updateTitle', e.target.value);
      },
      addTodo() {
          this.$store.commit('addTodo');      
      }
}
```

store.js

```
state() {
    return{
      todo: {
        title: '',
      },

      todos: [
      ]
   };\
},
mutations: {
    updateTitle(state, title) {
      state.todo.title = title;
    },
    addTodo(state) {
      state.todos.push(state.todo);
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure why it is changing what is already pushed to the array.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the nature of Vuex, you have only and only one copy of the data inside your state object, so pushing state.todo to the array pushes the only copy of todo that you have in your state, so when you update it again it changes the reference inside the array, you need to push a new element to your state, you need to receive the title in the "addTodo" method and create and push the new object:

```
addTodo(state, t) {
  state.todos.push({title: t});
}
```

Comment: If i were to add more items to the Todo state though, is there a way to make a deep copy of the state.todo and push that into the addTodo array?

Comment: What do you mean by a deep copy? Can you show an example?